# function that creates a new words by given pattern

Tags: python, function

im trying to create a function that takes a word (capital letters and lowercase letters) and map each character to a new character. the pattern is each vowel (AEIOU) becomes the next vowel in order (A -> E, E - > I). For constant letters becomes the thirds letter (B -> F, C -> G)

```
>>>'hello'
'lippu'
>>> 'today'
'xuhec'
>>> 'yesterday'
'ciwxivhec'
```

I know that i would have to create two lists:

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
constants = ['b', 'c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p', 'q','r', 's','t','v','w','x','y', 'z']
```

and uses the index() function, to check the current index and add 3 to it, but im stuck after that.

Letters loop back around for cases that extend beyond the list. (x-z, and u)

Comment: What happens to constant letters for example: Z, z: where we can't add 3 to the index?

Comment: @killuminati as well as `u`

Comment: it will start at a again so (z -> d)  (u -> a) @vash_the_stampede @ killuminati

Comment: is z -> c or z -> d?

Answer (score 2):

To compute the maps you can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) (to get the index of the current) together with modulo (for the indices greater than the list length), something like this:

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

vowels_map = {k: vowels[(i + 1) % len(vowels)] for i, k in enumerate(vowels)}
consonants_map = {k: consonants[(i + 3) % len(consonants)] for i, k in enumerate(consonants)}

print(vowels_map)
print(consonants_map)
```

**Output**

```
{'u': 'a', 'a': 'e', 'o': 'u', 'e': 'i', 'i': 'o'}
{'s': 'w', 'z': 'd', 'v': 'y', 'm': 'q', 'f': 'j', 'h': 'l', 'd': 'h', 'g': 'k', 'q': 't', 'n': 'r', 'p': 's', 'k': 'n', 't': 'x', 'y': 'c', 'r': 'v', 'w': 'z', 'x': 'b', 'l': 'p', 'b': 'f', 'j': 'm', 'c': 'g'}
```

Note that dictionaries have no order, that being said you could use them in the following way:

```
def replace_from_dict(word, table):
    return ''.join(table[c] for c in word)


words = ['hello',
         'today',
         'yesterday']

for word in words:
    print(replace_from_dict(word, { **vowels_map, **consonants_map }))
```

**Output** *(from using replace_from_dict)*

```
lippu
xuhec
ciwxivhec
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `itertools.cycle`. First check which category `i` belongs to either `vowel` or `consonants` (not constant). Then create a `cycle` from that respective list, use `while` and `next` until we are at the corresponding letter. If its a `vowel` we simply append the `next` value, if its a `consonant` we advance 2 positions and then append the `next` value. After use `.join()` to convert back to string.

```
from itertools import cycle

vwl = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
cnst = ['b', 'c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p', 'q','r', 's','t','v','w','x','y', 'z']

s = 'hello'
new = []
for i in s.lower():
    if i in vwl:
        a = cycle(vwl)
        while i != next(a):
            next(a)    
        new.append(next(a))
    if i in cnst:
        b = cycle(cnst)
        while i != next(b):
            next(b)
        for x in range(2):
            next(b)
        new.append(next(b))

res = ''.join(new)
print(res)
# lippu
```

Works for words that include edge letters, `zumba` produces `daqfe`

Comment: oh, I was thinking of using mod (%) to wrap around the list. Will that work? (assuming we are unable to import)

Comment: @errick-michael-santos sorry no longer by PC but hmm if I were not to use cycle I would prob use try except and once stop iteration occurs restart the iter and continue, can show when I return would work the same as the cycle concept just manual going back to the beginning

Answer (score 0):

I have defined two dictionaries for edge cases, vowel_dictionary, and a dictionary for letters x/y/z to achieve wrapping. I iterated through the string and if the character is a special character, I use the appropriate dictionary to find the word. However if the character is below 'w' and not a vowel, I just add 4 to its `ord` value (ASCII value) and convert it char.

```
def transform(input):
  return_string = ""
  vowel_dictionary = {
    'a': 'e',
    'e': 'i',
    'i': 'o',
    'o': 'u',
    'u': 'a'
  }
  edge_dictionary = {
    'x': 'b',
    'y': 'c',
    'z': 'd'
  }
  for character in input.lower():
    if character in vowel_dictionary:
      return_string += vowel_dictionary[character]
    elif ord(character) <= ord("v"):
      return_string += chr(ord(character) + 4)
    else :
      return_string += edge_dictionary[character]

  return return_string
```

I have ran a few tests with the code above:

**Tests**

```
transform("hello") # => lippu

transform("today") # => xuhec

transform("yesterday") # => ciwxivhec
```